# Difference between ubuntu systemd simple(oneshot) and forking?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test.jar >> /home/ubuntu/radius/radius.log &
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test-2.jar >> /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-2.log &
```

I have a script file like the one above and it should run automatically at boot time.

Among the many methods I found out, I decided to use systemd and succeeded in getting the desired behavior.

However, I would like to know if there is a correct way to specify the Type option or if there is no problem.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script

[Service]
Type=simple or oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/radius/radius-start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


---

[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/radius/radius-start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In both methods, the service runs when booting up, and my jar file runs as well.
And the service is still active and the jar process is maintained as well.
Then, when the service is terminated, all jar processes are also terminated.

I looked it up and found that forking is suitable for a background method, the child process runs, and then the parent process dies. (I don't understand this part either.)
It also says that a pid file must be specified or that the forking method is not used.

Simple or oneshot is said to be used in a way that requires operation in the foreground.
But my jar process needs to run in the background.

What is the difference between the two methods?
Which option is the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the two versions of your unit file, and then I'll show you what I would suggest:

#### `simple` or `oneshot` service

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/radius/radius-start.sh
```

`Type=oneshot` is more appropriate to use with `RemainAfterExit=yes` than `Type=simple`.

With `simple` you normally run `ExecStart=`.  Then when that process ends, everything is cleaned up and the service is "stopped".  However, `radius-start.sh` launches some processes and then stops immediately.  That means systemd will look for any orphaned processes and kill them as part of the clean-up.

With `oneshot`, that is really meant to run `ExecStart=` and then die.  `RemainAfterExit=` can use useful to help you trigger `ExecStop=` commands or make use of `ConsistsOf=` relationships to stop other units when this unit is stopped.  But it isn't giving you an up-to-date status of the child processes you spawned.

The big issue with this technique is that it will either kill your (orphaned) child processes immediately, or it will not understand that the unit is stopped/failed when the child processes exit.

---

#### `forking` service

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/radius/radius-start.sh
```

This is the correct version of your service. `forking` will run `ExecStart=`, which is expected to exit very quickly.  systemd then expects some spawned child processes, and will track the state of those.  When the main process exits, systemd will consider the service to be stopped.

If you stick with this method, then it is recommended to set `PIDFile=` so that systemd understands which of your two processes is the main one.

```
[Service]
...
PIDFile=/run/myservice.pid
...
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test.jar >> /home/ubuntu/radius/radius.log &
echo $! > /run/myservice.pid
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test-2.jar >> /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-2.log &
```

However, systemd's documentation explicitly states:

> Note that PID files should be avoided in modern projects. Use Type=notify or Type=simple where possible, which does not require use of PID files to determine the main process of a service and avoids needless forking.

Calling `bash` here to run your process is unnecessary as everything you want to do is already supplied by systemd natively.

---

#### Verbatim suggestion with `Type=simple`

If I were to implement your service verbatim, I would implement it with two services:

```
# radius-test.service
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test.jar
StandardOutput=append:/home/ubuntu/radius/radius.log
```

```
# radius-test2.service
[Unit]
After=radius-test.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test-2.jar
StandardOutput=append:/home/ubuntu/radius/radius-2.log
```

Now if one of the services fails, we can detect which one failed and recover it.  If these services need some sort of relationship, those can be defined.  Ordering, for example, can be achieved with `After=`.  If you want one to stop cleanly when the other fails, you could add `BindsTo=`.

---

#### Improving the solution

- `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 2`:  This is usually a hack.  A delay introduces unnecessary delay on good days, or not enough delay on bad days.  It's better to understand why you needed to sleep.  For example, if you need the network to be available before running your service, use `After=network.target` instead.
- `Type=simple`:  This is actually the default.  So the line can be removed.
- If you always want to run radius-test2 when starting radius-test, then use a `Wants=` relationship (or specify `WantedBy=radius-test` in `radius-test2`'s `[Install]` section)
- If you want to stop `radius-test2` when `radius-test` is stopped, then use a `PartOf=` relationship.
- `StandardOutput=append:...`: While there isn't a problem with logging things to your own file, you may find it convenient to use the built-in journal.  By simply removing this line, you can get your logs via `journalctl -u myservice.service`.  `journalctl` provides lots of extra functionality like log rotating, size limits, and filtering.  I frequently do stuff like this:

`journalctl -u myservice --since "5 hours ago" --until "4 hours ago"`

An improved version would be this:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/radius-test.service
[Unit]
Description=Radius Test 1
After=network.target
Before=radius-test-2
Wants=radius-test-2

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user-target

# /etc/systemd/system/radius-test2.service
[Unit]
Description=Radius Test 2
PartOf=radius-test

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test-2.jar
```

#### The final simple solution

However, now that we have removed `StandardOutput=` and used the journal, it's also possible to combine these into one unit.  This is a simpler solution using `ExecStartPost=`:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/radius-test.service
[Unit]
Description=Radius Test
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test.jar
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/radius/radius-test-2.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user-target
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I followed your example and it works correctly. However, the worrying part is that the content of the script I presented as an example is very short. If this script is long, is it still correct to input everything into the service?

What should I do if I have to use a script (sh)?

Comment: Most scripts follow the same type of pattern:  set some environment variables, setup logging, fork a process, save the PID, and exit.  Instead of writing your own bash script to do it, systemd implements those patterns in its service, providing more globally configurable and consistent behaviour.  Even things like conditionals are supported.  If you ask another question with a larger script, we can show you how to systemd-ify it.

Comment: If you HAVE to use a script (this often means you are running some older software daemon-ized in the sysV days), then `forking` is the correct solution.

Comment: I learned something new about systemd. Thank you.